# How to increment a counter in a nested loop?

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code that creates a canvas grid, each cell rendering an image. What I want to do is to persist a counter that increments by 1 from the first cell of the grid, to the last one, across the second nested loop.

```
window.onload = function() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.strokeStyle = "grey";
  ctx.lineWidth = 4;
  
  //draw grid
  for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    const x = i*60;
    ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
    ctx.stroke();
    
    const y = i*60;
    ctx.moveTo(0, y);
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  
  const p = ctx.lineWidth / 3;
  // draw images  
  for (let xCell = 0; xCell < 10; xCell++) {
    for (let yCell = 0; yCell < 10; yCell++) {
      const x = xCell * 60;
      const y = yCell * 60;
      const img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, x+p, y+p, 60-p*2, 60-p*2);
      };
      img.src = `https://dummyimage.com/60x60/000/fff&text=x${xCell},y${yCell}`;
    }
  }
};
```

The above code produces this canvas:
[image: canvas]

Edit: Perhaps the question and what I wanted to do weren't quite clear. I have a nested loop that draws a cell in the amount of `xCell` times `yCell`, with their coordinates to form a grid. What I wanted to do was to map an index to each cell, starting from the upper left (from coordinates x0, y0), going to the lower right (x9, y9). So the cell x0 y0 would have an index of 0, and x9 y9 of index 99.

The solution was to do a simple calculation inside the nested loop like the following:

```
const cellIndex = xCell + 10 * yCell;
```

This way I get the following result:

[image: canvas]

Comment: So you want to replace these `x0,y0`, `x1,y0` by `1`, `2` etc. - or what exactly?

Comment: what have you tried so far? the problem seems pretty easy, so easy in fact that i'm not sure i understood you correctly, can you provide some debugging details?

Comment: What have you tried to increment a variable for each one?

Answer (score 2):

So I guess you want to know the 'cell number', what you call the counter that increment towards the second loop. If so, you don't need to increment it, you can calculate.

```
 for (let x = 0; x < XMAX; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < YMAX; y++) {
      let counter = x * YMAX + y; 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Alternatively you could remove the nested loop and calculate `x` and `y` from `counter`. `for (let counter = 0; counter < XMAX * YMAX; counter++)` then within the loop `const x = Math.floor(counter / YMAX)` and `const y = counter % x`.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use a variable which you can increment inside the loop like this:

```
let my_variable = 0;

for (let xCell = 0; xCell < 10; xCell++) {
    for (let yCell = 0; yCell < 10; yCell++) {
      
      my_variable++;
      console.log(my_variable);

      //Other stuff
    }
  }
```

This will log every number from 1 up to 100 (each cycle will increase the number with one)

---

As @3limin4t0r suggested, if you want to use your number to access an array you are iterating with your loops, you could use the variable before incrementing it (increment at the end of the inner loop).This way you would get the numbers from 0 to 99 and you could use it to access the objects inside an array.

```
let my_variable = 0;

for (let xCell = 0; xCell < 10; xCell++) {
    for (let yCell = 0; yCell < 10; yCell++) {
      
      console.log(my_variable);
      //Other stuff
      
      var current_cell = arrOfCells[my_variable];
      //Do something with the cell

      my_variable++;
    }
  }
```

Comment: The reason it is unlogical is that you basically start using it from 1. Whereas counters/indexes usually start or end on 0. Furthermore you initialize it to 0, but never use it as 0. I would personally initialize it in the first for loop, `let xCell = 0, counter = 0` then increment it in the second for loop, `yCell++, counter++`.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Thats a valid point to start with 0 for accessing arrays via indexing. But since there is no array in the code of this question and the question ultimately was only about incrementing a counter in a nested loop, I thought this was an easier example to show how to do so. I have added your suggestion to my answere.